# Could not find a supported SingleSignonServiceEndpoint

Tags: simplesamlphp

I am setting up federated login for my application using `simplesamlphp` I keep getting the error Could not find a supported SingleSignonServiceEndpoint. From my research that happens when the IDP wants to use http-post. That is indeed the default according to the metadata xml, but it also supports http-redirect as a tertiary option. I changed the php to make http-redirect the default by adding `isDefault` to the `http-redirect` method, still getting the same error. What is interesting is that if we go to the adfs login portal first and log in, the redirect is no longer necessary and so we get the claims back that we expect. Otherwise we get the error.

**AuthSources.php**

```
<?php

$config = array(

    // This is a authentication source which handles admin authentication.
    'admin' => array(
        // The default is to use core:AdminPassword, but it can be replaced with
        // any authentication source.

        'core:AdminPassword',
    ),


    // An authentication source which can authenticate against both SAML 2.0
    // and Shibboleth 1.3 IdPs. If you make any configuration changes, you will need
    // to update the RPT at the IdP.
    'app' => array(
        'saml:SP',

        // The entity ID of this SP.
        // Can be NULL/unset, in which case an entity ID is generated based on the metadata URL.
        'entityID' => null,

        // !!CHANGE ME!!
        // The entity ID of the IdP this should SP should contact.
        // Should be the same as the IDP listed in the metadata from SimpleSAMLphp.
        'idp' => 'http://********/adfs/services/trust',

        // The URL to the discovery service.
        // Can be NULL/unset, in which case a builtin discovery service will be used.
        'discoURL' => null,

        // ADFS 2012R2 requires signing of the logout - the others are optional (may be overhead you don't want.)
        'sign.logout' => true,
        'redirect.sign' => true,
        'assertion.encryption' => true,
        // We now need a certificate and key. The following command (executed on Linux usually)
        // creates a self-signed cert and key, using SHA256, valid for 2 years.
        // openssl req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my.key -out my.pem
        'privatekey' => 'sw.key',
        'certificate' => 'sw.crt',
        // Enforce the use of SHA-256 by default.
        'signature.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256'
    ),

);
```

**saml20-idp-remote.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * SAML 2.0 remote IdP metadata for SimpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * Remember to remove the IdPs you don't use from this file.
 *
 * See: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-reference-idp-remote 
 */

$metadata['http://********/adfs/services/trust'] = array (

  'entityid' => 'http://********/adfs/services/trust',

  'contacts' => 

  array (

    0 => 

    array (

      'contactType' => 'support',

    ),

  ),

  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-sp-remote',

  'AssertionConsumerService' => 

  array (

    0 => 

    array (

      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',

      'Location' => 'https://********/adfs/ls/',

      'index' => 0,

    ),

    1 => 

    array (

      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',

      'Location' => 'https://********/adfs/ls/',

      'index' => 1,

    ),

    2 => 

    array (

      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',

      'Location' => 'https://********/adfs/ls/',

      'index' => 2,

      'isDefault' => true

    ),

  ),

  'SingleLogoutService' => 

  array (

    0 => 

    array (

      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',

      'Location' => 'https://********/adfs/ls/',

    ),

    1 => 

    array (

      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',

      'Location' => 'https://********/adfs/ls/',

    ),

  ),

  'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',

  'keys' => 

  array (

    0 => 

    array (

      'encryption' => true,

      'signing' => false,

      'type' => 'X509Certificate',

      'X509Certificate' => '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',

    ),

    1 => 

    array (

      'encryption' => false,

      'signing' => true,

      'type' => 'X509Certificate',

      'X509Certificate' => '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',

    ),

  ),

  'saml20.sign.assertion' => true,

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `SingleSignOnService` configuration in your `saml20-idp-remote.php`. That file needs to list the correct binding and url for your IdP.

```
// Example
'SingleSignOnService' =>
    array (
        0 =>
            array (
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
                'Location' => 'https://someidp.cirrusidentity.com/sso/saml',
            ),
        1 =>
            array (
                'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
                'Location' => 'https://someidp.cirrusidentity.com/sso/saml',
            ),
    ),
```